# If Statement - efficient handling of condition

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I could do with some advice on the most efficient way of handling this statement.

I have UISwitch that if switched `on` places a tick in a box.  There are hundreds of these boxes

Rather than

```
if (_tickSwitch.on){


  _tickBox1.textValue =  @"√" ;
  _tickBox2.textValue =  @"√" ;
  _tickBox3.textValue =  @"√" ;
  _tickBox4.textValue =  @"√" ;
```

etc....

Im trying to work out how I can just have a condition that asks if anything that has `textValue` set the text as √

so something like

```
   anyValueThatIs.textValue =  @"√" ;
```

I cant think of the sytax that allows - anything with preceding value, do this

Comment: Pretty an array of _tickBoxes is the best you're gonna do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the same target for actions to all your `UISwitch` components, eg:

```
[item addTarget:self action:@selector(toggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

so that you can catch the event and behave accordingly:

```
- (IBAction) toggled:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *item = (UISwitch*)sender;
    if (item.on)
      item.textValue = @"√";
}
```

Of course you need a loop of all your `UISwitch*` components otherwise you are just moving verbosity somewhere else. Another solution would be to subclass them to a `CustomUISwitch` component which adds the target in the costructor thus avoiding the need of a container.

Answer (score 0):

You should place all your tickBox in an array, and then loop that array to perform your tests